# Заполнение в шахматном порядке Python array

Tags: python, массивы, list

Задача:
Заполните прямоугольный массив целыми числами начиная с единицы по строчкам слева направо,строчки обходятся сверху вниз. При этом в левом верхнем углу записано число 1, далее заполняются только клетки, имеющие тот же цвет в шахматной раскраске, что и левый верхний угол, а в остальных клетках записано число 0.

Пример для n=5m=6:

```
1  0  2  0  3  0 
0  4  0  5  0  6 
7  0  8  0  9  0 
0 10  0 11  0 12 
13  0 14  0 15  0
```

Мое решение:

```
n, m = 5, 6
a = []
x = 0
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
for j in range(m):
    if (i+j+1)%2 == 0 :
        a[i].append(0)
    else:
        x += 1
        a[i].append(x)
for k in a:
   print(k)
```

Как записать это с помощью генератора, а точнее, не знаю как x+=1 должно выглядеть в генераторе?

```
 N, M = 5, 6
 x = 0
 arr = [[0 if (i+j+1)%2 == 0 else ??? for j in range(N)] for i in range(M)]
```

Хотелось бы также увидеть ваши варианты решения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так:

```
In [39]: arr = [[0 if (i+j)%2 else (i*M+j)//2+1 for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

In [40]: arr
Out[40]:
[[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6],
 [7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0],
 [0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12],
 [13, 0, 14, 0, 15, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал не городить всю логику в генераторе списка, а вынести её в отдельную функцию, оставив в генераторе списка только собственно формирование матрицы.

```
from itertools import count


def my_sequence():
    cnt = count(1)  # Последовательность 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
    while True:
        yield next(cnt)
        yield 0


N, M = 5, 6
seq = my_sequence()
arr = [[next(seq) for j in range(N)] for i in range(M)]


# Можно напечатать и обычным print,
# но pretty print выводит матрицы в гораздо более наглядной форме

from pprint import pprint

pprint(arr)
```